# Debugging in iOS / callStackReturnAddresses and callStackSymbols

Tags: ios, debugging, exception, symbolicate

i set an uncaughtExceptionHandler in my iOS app and got the following data from a user but i don't know how to interpret them to find the location of the error.
What is the number behind the plus sign for? how can i use the addresses to get the location of the error?

**callStackReturnAddresses**

```
(0x305b1f53 0x3ac1a6af 0x304e85f3 0xe7cd5 0x32d3d419 0x32eb3e0b 0x32dd1a83 0x32dd188d 0x32dd1825 0x32d23023 0x329ac24b 0x329a7a5b 0x329a78ed 0x329a72ff 0x329a710f 0x329a0e3d 0x3057d1d5 0x3057ab79 0x3057aebb 0x304e5ce7 0x304e5acb 0x351b3283 0x32d87a41 0xb51d7 0xb5198)
```

**callStackSymbols**

```
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x305b1f6b <redacted> + 154
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3ac1a6af objc_exception_throw + 38
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x304e85f3 <redacted> + 230
    3   MyApp                               0x000e7cd5 MyApp + 236757
    4   UIKit                               0x32d3d419 <redacted> + 472
    5   UIKit                               0x32eb3e0b <redacted> + 834
    6   UIKit                               0x32dd1a83 <redacted> + 418
    7   UIKit                               0x32dd188d <redacted> + 44
    8   UIKit                               0x32dd1825 <redacted> + 184
    9   UIKit                               0x32d23023 <redacted> + 346
    10  QuartzCore                          0x329ac24b <redacted> + 142
    11  QuartzCore                          0x329a7a5b <redacted> + 350
    12  QuartzCore                          0x329a78ed <redacted> + 16
    13  QuartzCore                          0x329a72ff <redacted> + 230
    14  QuartzCore                          0x329a710f <redacted> + 314
    15  QuartzCore                          0x329a0e3d <redacted> + 56
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x3057d1d5 <redacted> + 20
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x3057ab79 <redacted> + 284
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x3057aebb <redacted> + 730
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x304e5ce7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x304e5acb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x351b3283 GSEventRunModal + 138
    22  UIKit                               0x32d87a41 UIApplicationMain + 1136
    23  MyApp                               0x000b51d7 MyApp + 29143
    24  MyApp                               0x000b5198 MyApp + 29080
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbols are not reliable available device-side, and on iOS 6 and later, many system symbols will simply be `<redacted>`.

From here: https://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/issues/detail?id=40